# How would I add array values to Model data dynamically for a Strongly-Typed View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the programming environment.

- Framework: ASP.NET Framework 4
- Language: Visual C# 2010
- Design Pattern: MVC 4
- View Engine: Razor

Here is the scenario.

I'm creating a web page with the following codes:

## ProjectTracking.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class ProjectTracking
    {
        public int ProjectID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string ProjectName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DateTime ProjectDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

## ProjectTrackingController.cs

```
using ProjectTracking.Models;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespsace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectTrackingController:Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProjectTracking[] projects =
            {
                new ProjectTracking
                {
                    ProjectID = 1,
                    ProjectName = "Project 1",
                    ProjectDate = DateTime.Now
                },
                new ProjectTracking
                {
                    ProjectID = 2,
                    ProjectName = "Project 2",
                    ProjectDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
                },
                new ProjectTracking
                {
                    ProjectID = 3,
                    ProjectName = "Project 3",
                    ProjectDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
                }
            };
        }

        public ActionResult New()
        {
            ...omitted for brevity...
        }
    }
}
```

## Index.cshtml

```
@using MyProject.Models
@model ProjectTracking[]
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Tracking";
}
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add a New Project", "New")
</p>
@if (Model.Length > 0)
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (ProjectTracking p in Model
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @p.ProjectID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @p.ProjectName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @p.ProjectDate
                    </td>
                 </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else
{
    <h2>No project tracking data found.</h2>
}
```

This seems to work so far. Here is the challenge I'm facing. I'd like to insert results from an array to ProjectID instead. What would I need to do to make this happen?

For example,

```
        int[] projectInt = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProjectTracking[] projects =
            {
                new ProjectTracking
                {
                    ProjectID = projectInt???...
```

Maybe this is a bad approach and would require a different strategy altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int[] projectInt = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };

    List<ProjectTracking> projects = new List<ProjectTracking>();
    foreach (var i in projectInt)
    {
      var project = new ProjectTracking{
                            ProjectID = projectInt[i],
                            ...
      }
      projects.Add(project);
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error message when I tried that: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List` 1[MyProject.Models.ProjectTracking]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.ProjectTracking[]'.

Comment: Sorry, instead of using `List<ProjectTracking> projects`, use `ProjectTracking[] projects`

Comment: Oh, never mind! I revised the View to use @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.ProjectTracking> and it's working fine and dandy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       int[] projectInt = new int[3]{1, 2, 3};
       List<ProjectTracking> projects = new List<ProjectTracking>();
       for(var i in projectInts)
       {
            projects.Add(
            new ProjectTracking
            {
                ProjectID = projectInt[i],
                ProjectName = "Project " + projectInt[i],
                ProjectDate = DateTime.Add(projectInt[i])
            });
        }
       return View(projects)
    }
```